# Await returns too soon

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, amazon-sagemaker, mechanicalturk

I am retrieving a list of image filenames from DynamoDB and using those image filenames to replace the default `src=` image in a portion of a website.

I'm a JS novice, so I'm certainly missing something, but my function is returning the list of filenames too late.

My inline script is:

```
<script>
        customElements.whenDefined( 'crowd-bounding-box' ).then( () => {  
        var imgBox = document.getElementById('annotator');
        newImg = imageslist();
        console.log("Result of newImg is: " + newImg);
        imgBox.src = "https://my-images-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" + newImg;
    } )
</script>
```

My JS function is:

```
async function imageslist() {
    const username = "sampleuser";
    const params = {
        TableName: "mytable",
        FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(" + username + ")",
        ReturnConsumedCapacity: "NONE"
    };
    try {
        var data = await ddb.scan(params).promise()
        var imglist = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < data.Items.length; i++) {
            imglist.push(data.Items[i].img.S);
        };
        imglist.sort();
        var firstimg = imglist[0];
        console.log(firstimg);
        return imglist
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

The console reports `Result of newImg is: [object Promise]` and shortly after that, it reports the expected filename.  After the page has been rendered, I can input `newImg` in the console and I receive the expected result.

Am I using the **await** syntax improperly?

Side note: This site uses the Crowd HTML Elements (for Ground Truth and Mechanical Turk), so I'm forced to have the `src=` attribute present in my `crowd-bounding-box` tag and it must be a non-zero value.  I'm loading a default image and replacing it with another image.

Comment: You aren't awaiting `imageslist();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you use the `await` keyword, you must use the `async` keyword before the function definition (which you have done). The thing is, any time an async function is called, it will always return a `Promise` object since it expects that some asynchronous task will take place within the function.

Therefore,you'll need to `await` the result of the imageslist function and make the surrounding function `async`.

```js
<script>
    customElements.whenDefined( 'crowd-bounding-box' ).then( async () => {  
        var imgBox = document.getElementById('annotator');
        newImg = await imageslist();
        console.log("Result of newImg is: " + newImg);
        imgBox.src = "https://my-images-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/" + newImg;
    } )
</script>
```

Comment: Mister Wizard!  I was hoping it was something that simple.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 1):

Your `async/await` code seems correct, but it's normal that you page is rendered before the promise is resolved. It's often like that with API call.

You should call a function that replace the `src` dynamically for all your images, at the end of your `imageslist` function